# Emacs: make debug-on-error catch errors

Tags: emacs, elisp

When I open an empty haskell file, which activates `haskell-mode`, I get the message

```
user-error: No items suitable for an index found in this buffer
```

If I do the same thing, but call `toggle-debug-on-error` beforehand, I get the same message: it doesn't enter the debugger when `user-error` is signalled.

How do I make emacs enter the debugger on `user-error`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Good question!**  The answer is to remove `user-error` from option `debug-ignored-errors`.  `M-x customize-option debug-ignored-errors`, and remove the entry for `user-error`.

However, IMO the Emacs manual should be transparent about this, and it is not.  Even the Elisp manual is not clear about this -- the only hint is this mention in passing, within the description of option `debug-ignored-errors`:

> The normal value of this variable includes `user-error', as well as several errors that happen often during editing but rarely result from bugs in Lisp programs.  However, "rarely" is not "never"; if your program fails with an error that matches this list, you may try changing this list to debug the error.  The easiest way is usually to set`debug-ignored-errors' to `nil'.

FWIW, I've submitted [Emacs bug #18005](http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=18005) for the missing doc.

Comment: Thank you. Setting `debug-ignored-errors` to `nil` solved the problem.

Comment: FWIW, Emacs Dev closed the doc bug I reported for this, as **wont-fix**.  But [RMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_Stallman) just posted a [reply in the bug thread](http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=18005#16), agreeing with me.